# How To Load Javascript Files After DOMContentLoaded

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to load Javascript files after `DOMContentLoaded`? I have tried using `defer` but it loads before `DOMContentLoaded`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using following files in my HTML.

```
<script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/4.0.0/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use an eventListener and append the scripts to the DOM

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  let script = document.createElement('script');
  // script.src = 'script.js'; // use this to set the source
  script.innerHTML = 'alert(1)'
  document.body.appendChild(script);
});
```